# How to include plots in a new engine

Tags: r, knitr

I'm writing a new engine for knitr.  This engine can, depending on the input, generate a plot as either a ggplot object (list) or stored in a file (.png).  I'm trying to output the image to the html (pdf, md) file that is generated by knitr but cannot find how.

I've tried:

- `include_graphics()` with the path of the file
- return the ggplot object in `engine_output()` function
- `knit_print()` with many options

nothing works!

Here is the code of the engine.  It's an engine for Ruby on GraalVM (Galaaz).  Calling `GalaazUtil.exec_ruby` will execute the Ruby code on the same R process of knitr and return in `out` the output of the execution.

When a plot in generated, there is no output... how does **knitr** identify that a plot was generated in the R chunk?

Now assuming that I have access to the generated image in a file, how to I make this show in my knitr html page?

```
eng_ruby = function(options) {
  block_code = paste(options$code, collapse = "\\n");
  code = paste0("GalaazUtil.exec_ruby(", 
                   shQuote(block_code), 
                  ")
                ");
  out = eval.polyglot("ruby", code);
  engine_output(options, block_code, out)
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the "Details" section on the help page `?knitr::engine_output`. You can use `knitr::include_graphics()`. Here is a toy example (include the R logo):

````
```{r}
knitr::knit_engines$set(Rlogo = function(options) {
  path = 'logo.jpg'
  file.copy(file.path(R.home('doc'), 'html', 'logo.jpg'), path)
  knitr::engine_output(options, out = list(knitr::include_graphics(path)))
})
```

```{Rlogo}
Whatever.
```
````

Comment: It looks like this only outputs something when the document is knit, is there a way to also show the image when the chunk is ran in the rmarkdown document?

Comment: @retorquere Unfortunately, no.