# knit engine for graphs does not show code and result at the same time

Tags: r, knitr

This is a follow up to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54700702/632423

I would like to include the graph and the code.

So I have the following `Rmd` file which should output the graph (depending on `eval`) and the code (depending on `echo`), but instead of the graph, it gives the file name.

How can I make it, that it shows the graph and the code? I thought, this is internally controlled by the `options` passed to `knitr::engine_output()`, but as soon as `code` is specified, I only get the file name?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::knit_engines$set(Rlogo = function(options) {
  if (options$eval) {
    path <- 'logo.jpg'
    file.copy(file.path(R.home('doc'), 'html', 'logo.jpg'), path)
    out <- list(knitr::include_graphics(path))
  } else {
    out = ""
  }
  if (options$echo) {
    code <- options$code
  } else {
    code <- ""
  }
  knitr::engine_output(
    options, 
    out = out,
    code = code
  )
})
```


```{Rlogo echo = TRUE, eval = TRUE}
Whatever.
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - I found a solution:

````
--
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::knit_engines$set(Rlogo = function(options) {
  result <- list(cose = "", out = "")
  if (options$eval) {
    path <- 'logo.jpg'
    file.copy(file.path(R.home('doc'), 'html', 'logo.jpg'), path)
    result$out <- knitr::engine_output(
      options, 
      out = list(knitr::include_graphics(path))
    )
  }
  if (options$echo)
  result$code <- knitr::engine_output(
    options, 
    code = options$code,
    out = NULL
  )
  return(paste(result$code, result$out, sep = "\n\n"))
})
```


```{Rlogo, echo = TRUE, eval = TRUE}
Whatever.
```
````

It works, because the function `knitr::engine_output()` just returns a string. These two strings just need to be appended with two linefeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

````r
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::knit_engines$set(Rlogo = function(options) {
    out <- list("")
  if (options$eval) {
    path <- 'logo.jpg'
    file.copy(file.path(R.home('doc'), 'html', 'logo.jpg'), path)
    out <- list(knitr::include_graphics(path))
  }
  if (options$echo)
    out <- c(out, options$code)
  knitr::engine_output(
    options, 
    out = out
  )
})
```


```{Rlogo, echo = TRUE, eval = TRUE}
Whatever.
```
````

Comment: Thanks - that prints the code, but as it is in different lines, each kine is a single block. I also have no grey background as when I supply the code as the `code` argument. So no solution for me.